# Image over the div and does not have the same ratio with parent of div. Issuse with Firefox and IE9

Tags: html, css

I have code like a link ([jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/m6YPr/)) here.

Simple :

```
<div class="box"> 
  <img width="600" height="300" src="img.jpg"/>
</div>

.box{width:500px;}
.box img{max-width:100%;}
```

The image is fixed with permanent size (width and height). For the above design, Chrome runs it good, but Firefox and IE be error(the image over float outside of div ). Help me for solving it. Thank all suggestions.

Comment: if you want set width to image by style means you have to change img to block element... `img { display:block; }` ok.. :)

Comment: try : `.box{width:500px;}
.box img{width:100%;}`

Comment: Actually, I don't know which browser is right for this circumstance.  I may must give it follow width. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try : I think that would be enough.

```
.box{width:500px;}
.box img{width:100%;}
```

Comment: I have the same thinking with you.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

add this in your css, this gets your image back inside

```
img
{
height:auto;
width:auto;
display:block;
}
```

or

```
.box-content{padding:10px; height:auto; width:100%;}
.box-content img{max-width:95%; text-align:center; height:auto; width:100%;}
```

added the `width:100%` to the box

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/m6YPr/10/)

Comment: your demo is over floated. :)

Comment: nice work but I think there is no need to put them just `width:100%` would be enough.